# bash script is taking fixed argument values instead of those actually passed

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-arguments

I have simple bash script find.sh for finding the files

```
==>cat find.sh

echo $1

find -name $1
```

but it is not taking the correct arguments sometimes, instead it takes the fixed argument

Eg

```
find.sh 'ECSv2_P_TCP_FUNC_060*'

ECSv2_P_TCP_FUNC_060 ECSv2_P_TCP_FUNC_060.backup
```

Here though i have passed 'ECSv2_P_TCP_FUNC_060*' it has taken ECSv2_P_TCP_FUNC_060 ECSv2_P_TCP_FUNC_060.backup these as arguments.

Why does this happen?
And how to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is indeed taking the argument, but the script is expanding the * before passing it to echo and find is reading the argument and interpreting the *.  (Actually, find is probably bombing because the first arguemnt should be a directory.  eg, 'find . -name $1')

Comment: At least in GNU find, the manpage states: "If no paths are given, the current directory is used."

Comment: @Christoph  Other finds take it as a syntax error.  (BSD find certainly does!)

Comment: Thanks a lot!! combining answer 1 and 2 solved my problem. I was missing quotes as well as . required for specifying directoy.

Comment: @Christopher: It's different if the argument is a glob. Using GNU `find` with an existing file named "foo.txt" in the current directory and in a subdirectory below that one with the same name and one called "foo.txt.bak", plus a few other files at both levels, compare each of `find foo.*`, `find "foo.*", `find . "foo.*"`, `find -name "foo.*"`, `find . -name "foo.*"` and `find . -name foo.*`.

Answer (score 5):

You need to protect the * character from shell expansion inside the script as well:

```
echo "$1"
find . -name "$1"
```

(Edited to include the current directory as argument for find.)